# Sagemaker PysparkProcessor: specifying s3 code location

Tags: pyspark, amazon-sagemaker

`sagemaker.processing.FrameworkProcessor` accepts `code_location` parameter to specify the S3 prefix URI where custom code will be uploaded.  How do you the same with PysparkProcessor?  I know you there are `dependency_location` and `configuration_location` to specify the s3 location for dependencies and configurations, but I don't see any param to specify the code location.

By default, the script is uploaded to
`s3://my_bucket/my_job_name/input/code/my_custom_script.py`

This creates a lot of clutter under the root of the bucket.  Is there a way to change the s3 path?